# Create def with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to use list comprehension instead of a standard loop to define a function in python. Here I want to write a function, `get_index(CS, alpha)`, that takes a list CS and threshold alpha as inputs and returns the position, index, of the first element such that `CS[index] > alpha`.

For example:

```
CS = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9, 8, 12, 13, 12, 10, 9, 7, 9]

alpha = 12

assert get_index(CS, alpha) == 11
```

If no such element is found in CS, the function should return -1.

My following code fails due to `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

```
def get_index(CS, alpha):
    return i for i, v in enumerate(CS) if v > alpha
    return -1
```

But it works if I put it in a standard loop like:

```
def get_index(CS, alpha):
    for i, v in enumerate(CS):
        if v > alpha: 
            return i
    return -1
```

I cannot tell the difference and try to figure out why. Appreciate your ideas. Thank you.

Comment: list comprehensions require the opening and closing square brackets `[]`

Comment: List comprehensions don't do what you think they do. The result of a list comprehension is a list and you need to find just the index. Therefore, you basically cannot and should not do this with a list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you, Paritosh and zvone. So list comprehensions can only be applied to Lists? Is it possible to use them to define a function? I mean, after "return".

Comment: Nothing wrong with the for loop - it’s easy to read and you don’t have to operate over the whole list CS like a comprehension does, so like your example you can return/break once you have found the first larger value.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wish to use list comprehensions for this, do it as:

```py
def get_index(CS, alpha):
    l = [i for i, v in enumerate(CS) if v > alpha] or [-1]
    return l[0]
```

Though your second code is way better for many reasons.

The syntax error happens, because having two unconditional returns inside a function is not permitted.

Comment: Thank you kuco23. I've just realized the literal meaning of List Comprehensions which generate a list. By the way, why the number turns negative after I voted your answer "it is useful"?

Comment: No problem :) I don't really know as I am still new here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression, which is similar to a list comprehension but doesn't create a list.

Calling `next` evaluates the generator until the first result is found, or raises `StopIteration` if there is none.

```
try:
    return next(i for i, v in enumerate(CS) if v > alpha)
except StopIteration:
    return -1
```